# how to make a Copy formula, Value from A3 to B3 if z3 = csl

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007, vba

Is it possible to have a formula that can copy text value from A3 drop down list of cars, paste the text Value into B3, once i put CSl into Z3. then i can delete A3 but still have the text Value in B3.

or is this only done through a macro, and would i have to code this macro each time for each row.

could i put a tick box that could put "CSL" in Z3. and have the macro then do the copy paste values. and could this macro be used for the next row of cells B4, and to keep going down

thanks.

Comment: Can't be done by formulas alone, you would need a macro.

The answer is basically yes to all your questions :)

You can consider a macro that will automatically update B3 to the value of A3 once the dropdown is changed to a non-blank value.

You could consider having a tick box in Z3, that once ticked will copy A3 --> B3; put CSL where ever you want.

Need more information to be able to direct you better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you'd need something like this in the worksheet module for the workbook -

```
Private Sub worksheet_change(ByVal target As Range)
If Not Intersect(target, Range("Z3")) Is Nothing Then
    If Range("Z3") = "CSI" Then
        Range("B3") = Range("A3")
        Range("A3").ClearContents
    End If
End If
End Sub
```

You could change the range to reference the entire column and use `offset` to define what changes.